# Email verification and code approve

Tags: php, email

Currently I have 2 forms. On first user have to send code and receive it, and submit to second form and approve account. I need, when they put email and click submit, on email automatically is added code which they should get on their email, but they dont have to copy/paste code, because it should do automatically. Search for `mysql_query("UPDATE users SET verify = 'verified', bullets = bullets + 5000 WHERE ID = '$ida'");
        $showoutcome++; $outcome = "Your account is now verified!"; }` - Here I need to add, $verifnum, because that's the code which they should get on their email, but as I said script should approve it automatically, and I will use only one form where they enter just email and click verify.

```
<?php
    $saturate = "/[^a-z0-9]/i";
    $saturated = "/[^0-9]/i";
    $sessionidraw = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
    $sessionid = preg_replace($saturate,"",$sessionidraw);
    $userip = $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]; 
    $gangsterusername = $usernameone;
    $playerrank = $myrank;
    $playerarray =$statustesttwo;
    $playerrank = $playerarray['rankid'];
    $email = $playerarray['email'];
    $verified = $playerarray['verify'];
    $ref = $playerarray['ref'];

    if($verified == 'verified'){die('<font color=silver face=verdana size=1>Your account is already verified!'); }

    if($_POST['verify'] AND $_POST['email']){
    $newemail = $_POST['email'];
    if(!preg_match("/^[\ a-z0-9._-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{1,20}$/i", $_POST['email'])){ $showoutcome++; $outcome = "The email you entered is invalid!"; }else{
    $verifnum = rand(1111,9999);
    $to = "$newemail";
    $subject = "SG - Email Verification";
    $header = "From:  State Gangsters - Email Verification <admins@stategangsters.com>\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: State Gangsters <noreply@sgangsters.com>' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion() . "\r\n" .
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n";
    $body = "Your verification code is $verifnum!";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)){ $showoutcome++; $outcome = "An email has been sent, please check your inbox!";
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET verify = '$verifnum', email = '$newemail' WHERE ID = '$ida'");
    }}}

    if($_POST['code'] AND $_POST['verifyit']){
    $newcode = $_POST['code'];
    $getcodee = mysql_query("SELECT verify FROM users WHERE ID = '$ida'");
    $doit = mysql_fetch_array($getcodee);
    $getcode = $doit['verify'];
    if($newcode == $getcode AND $getcode > 0){
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET verify = 'verified', bullets = bullets + 5000 WHERE ID = '$ida'");
    $showoutcome++; $outcome = "Your account is now verified!"; }
    else{ $showoutcome++; $outcome = "The verification code you entered is incorrect!"; 
    }}
    ?>
```

Comment: The 1990's called and want their `<font>` tag back... Plus, how hard is is to to `$outcome = 'blah blah' . $verifnum;`?

Comment: Sidenote: `&&` has precedence over `AND` - and I assume you're already connected to DB, right? Ah, I knew that you were ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if($_POST['code'] AND $_POST['verifyit']) {
```

Change that to use `$_GET`, and create a link in your e-mail that will post back to the page with the appropriate variables, e.g.

```
$body = "Your verification code is <a href='$PHP_SELF?code=$verifnum&verifyit=1'>$verifnum</a>!";
```

This aside, your code is really messy (three functionalities in one script), full of obsolete things (`<font color=silver>`?), weird constructions (using `die` for regular program flow?) and guaranteed loopholes (`mysql_query` with variables inserted directly in the SQL?!?!!!). It's not clear where your `$ida` comes from anyway, but I'm guessing (hoping) that's a consequence of copy/pasting code here for a minimal example.